# What happened to McCean's question?

Tags: discussion

A member McCean (I hope I have his name right) asked for suggestions this morning (EST) regarding ethical systems, secular humanism, or something like that. I am sorry I can't remember the exact title or body of the question. It was a perfectly reasonable question in my opinion, especially when compared to some of other questions we get here.   It met with an objection from MichaelK that it was much (in bold) too broad. In the OP's response, he asked for feedback in order to improve his question.  Now I can't find the question. Can someone help me find it?

Comment: Title: Secular Philosophies of Self Control

Comment: Text: Outside of thought that deals with self control as it pertains to the supernatural and afterlife, I wonder what writing (and by who) has been put out there about self-control, self-transcendence, will-power, and that type of thing, but with more of a secular lean to it.

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 1):

[The question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/50971/secular-philosophies-of-self-control) was removed by its author. Because of this, the link will not work unless you have a significant amount of reputation points.

Comment: It says "page not found". Anyway, it's too bad he removed his question, maybe he will repost it. I would like to ask him why he removed his question.

Comment: @Gordon "Because of this, the link will not work unless you have a significant amount of reputation points."

Comment: Yes, you explained that above. The link does me no good ultimatey, but I thought the "title" would be listed.